# Configuring gradle to use JUnit, Mockito, Hamcrest and Espresso

Tags: android, junit, gradle, mockito, android-espresso

I have an Android project that uses Mockito, Hamcrest and Espresso to help with testing.

No matter what I try with the Gradle build file, I get a `NoSuchMethodError` for `org.hamcrest.Matcher.anyOf` when I try to run my tests after doing `gradle androidTestCompile`.

Here is my current configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':GameCore')
    androidTestCompile files(
            'libs/espresso-1.1.jar',
            'libs/testrunner-1.1.jar',
            'libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar'
    )
    androidTestCompile(
            'junit:junit:4.11',
            'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.0',
            'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0',
            'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
            )
```

I've tried rewriting the Mockito and JUnit requirements to exclude Hamcrest like so:

```
androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
}
```

But this doesn't make any difference.

The `GameCore` project is a pure Java project. It also has dependencies on JUnit and Mockito, but as they're specified as `testCompile`, I don't think they should be interfering.

The output for `gradle dependencies` for this module for 'androidTestCompile` is:

```
+--- junit:junit:4.11                                                               
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.0
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
+--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1
+--- com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0
+--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0
|    +--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0
|    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5 -> 1.10.0 (*)
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
\--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

**Edit**

Having further investigated the problem, I see that espresso needs Hamcrest 1.1, but I'm also using assertThat, which is in Hamcrest 1.3. Hamcrest 1.3 doesn't have the anyOf method that espresso uses. So I guess I'm stuck :)

Comment: Can you run `gradle dependencies` on that module and post the output for the relevant task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realised that `assertThat` is in Hamcrest 1.1, it's just in `hamcrest-integration` instead of `hamcrest-core`. I changed my build file and it's all working now:

```
androidTestCompile files(
        'libs/espresso-1.1.jar',
        'libs/testrunner-1.1.jar',
        'libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar'
)
androidTestCompile(
        'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5',
        'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0',
        'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0',
        'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
        'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
        'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
        'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
        'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
)
```

I tried using `espresso-1.1-bundled.jar` but that caused dex errors because two copies of Hamcrest 1.1 were pulled in, so I'd have had to exclude it from a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: Awesome! I am glad you got it working. I personally preferred Jake Wharton's bundled espresso package, but to each his own. Happy testing!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using all of those libraries in my Android Gradle project (I REALLY like testing and TDD as well :) ).

Here is the dependencies section of my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.43'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.43'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.1.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.+'

    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.9'

    //mockito dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-1.0.jar')

    //espresso dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.1.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

A lot of these you can probably ignore so here is a list with just the specific ones to testing:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':library')
    //noinspection GradleDependency

    //mockito dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-1.0.jar')

    //espresso dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.1.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') 
}
```

And the dexmaker libs can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/downloads/detail?name=dexmaker-1.0.jar&can=2&q=

and here:

https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/downloads/detail?name=dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar&can=2&q=

Comment: Thanks for posting your build file, but I don't see hamcrest in here. Is it in your libs directory?

Comment: Hamcrest comes with espresso so I expect it is all contained in that lib.

Comment: Ah OK. I'm not using the all-in-one version of espresso as I'm trying to avoid dependency clashes, hence I've included hamcrest separately